# How to pad the datetime column of a data frame?

Tags: r, padding, intervals

I have a dataframe that has an incomplete datetime variables. The interval of the data is the 0.5 second. I want to find what instances are missing and to insert a record for each of the missing time points.
For example, the data was shown below:

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1652182189, 1652182189, 1652182190, 1652182191
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), positionx = 3:6),
row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried to solve it with `pad()`:

```
pad(df, interval = " .5 sec")
```

However, there is an error as below because that the smallest unit of the interval of pad() is the sec.

```
Error: interval is not valid.
```

I want pad the dataframe as below. How do I solve this problem?

```
  time                positionx
  <dttm>                  <int>
1 2022-05-10 19:29:49         3
2 2022-05-10 19:29:49         4
3 2022-05-10 19:29:50         5
4 2022-05-10 19:29:50        NA
5 2022-05-10 19:29:51         6
```

Comment: Which package does the `pad` function come from?

Comment: It comes from the package of "padr".

Comment: So load it please

Comment: I have loaded it. But the problem is that the interval is 0.5 sec. However, it is not valid for the pad() .

Comment: Put `library(padr)` in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tibble(time=seq(min(df$time), max(df$time), by=seconds(0.5))) %>% 
  left_join(df, by="time")
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  time                positionx
  <dttm>                  <int>
1 2022-05-10 12:29:49         3
2 2022-05-10 12:29:49         4
3 2022-05-10 12:29:49        NA
4 2022-05-10 12:29:50         5
5 2022-05-10 12:29:50        NA
6 2022-05-10 12:29:51         6
```

**Edit**
In response to OP's question in comment.  (And I accept I should have spotted the difference between my output and OP's desired result before posting.)

I believe the problem is not in my algorithm, but in OP's input data.

Compare

```
strftime(df$time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3')
"2022-05-10 12:29:49.000" "2022-05-10 12:29:49.000" "2022-05-10 12:29:50.000" "2022-05-10 12:29:51.000"
```

with

```
strftime(seq(min(df$time), max(df$time), by=seconds(0.5)),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3')
[1] "2022-05-10 12:29:49.000" "2022-05-10 12:29:49.500" "2022-05-10 12:29:50.000" "2022-05-10 12:29:50.500" "2022-05-10 12:29:51.000"
```

In the input data, rows 1 and 2 represent the same time (at 12:29:49.000).  The algorithm *correctly* adds a third row at 12:29:49.500.  All three times appear identical using the default format used to display datetime objects in tibbles.

If OP's input data is instead,

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1652182189.0, 1652182189.5, 1652182190.0, 1652182191.0
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), positionx = 3:6),
row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then the output is

```
tibble(time=seq(min(df$time), max(df$time), by=seconds(0.5))) %>% 
  left_join(df, by="time")
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  time                positionx
  <dttm>                  <int>
1 2022-05-10 12:29:49         3
2 2022-05-10 12:29:49         4
3 2022-05-10 12:29:50         5
4 2022-05-10 12:29:50        NA
5 2022-05-10 12:29:51         6
```

As expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, in your output, there are three rows of "2022-05-10 12:29:49". I just want to add one row of "2022-05-10 19:29:50" into my dataframe. For my dataframe, the data collection frequency is 2Hz.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. What if i can not change my input data? I have 64 dataframes in CSV format.  The raw data is like the one shown in my example.  Could you please give me more inputs?

Comment: If you cannot change your data, then your statement that you are "sampling at 2Hz" is simply false.  If you cannot differentiate sampling times that differ by less than a second, then you have repeated sampling 1Hz, not single sampling at 2Hz.  However, importing from CSV is notoriously prone to subtle problems like this.  Do you have half second sampling in the source CSVs?  If so, then research how to import your date times correctly.  If you can't find an answer, post another question on SO.  And accept my answer here to indicate to others that your first problem has been resolved.